# Getting error when try to pattern match for Unix_error (Ocaml)?

Tags: exception, compiler-errors, pattern-matching, ocaml, utop

I've been trying to pattern for the case where a user types in an invalid directory:

```
# let dir = Unix.opendir "adfalf";;
Exception: Unix.Unix_error (Unix.ENOENT, "opendir", "adfalf").
```

My function is as follows:

```
let files_of_dir d = 
    try 
      let dir = Unix.opendir d in
      ...
    with
       Unix_error (uerr, ucommand, dir) -> raise Not_found
```

Except I keep getting the compilation error:

```
Error: This variant pattern is expected to have type exn
       The constructor Unix_error does not belong to type exn
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong w/ the pattern matching. If anyone could help me on this it would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Some Other Notes:**

I've been compiling my code using the following command on terminal:

```
ocamlbuild filename.byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say `Unix.Unix_error`, not just `Unix_error`. Note that this is what appears in your sample session.